# Advantage of defining a prototype in D-Specs in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I recently learned somthing about loacal procedures in fixed format RPG IV and their definition either in the D-Specs and implementation in P-Specs section or omitting the D-Specs definition.

According to the IBM Documentation, if I omit the definition in D the compiler will automatically generate the necessary definition from the procedure interface followed by the P-Spec where I implement my procedure.

Now I wonder what is the advantage of defining the procedure interface two times? Is there any benifit of writing (almost) the same code twice (in D-Specs in the top and below the P-Spec) or is this just a option for the programmer to have some meaningfull place where to define the input/outpu parameter for the procedure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting at IBM i v7.1, for internal procedures, there is no advantage to creating prototypes, and in fact there is a risk that you will get them wrong (though that issue is easily detected and corrected). Prior to that, all procedures required a prototype. For procedures that are exported from a service program, or a module, the prototypes are critical. I keep those in a separate copy book so that I can include the same prototypes in my module source, and in the source of the program using the module. In this way you only have to have a single copy of the prototypes floating around, and it is easy to include wherever you need them.

Comment: There's no advantage....originally you **had** to have a prototype for an internal procedure.  Now you don't.  But you'll probably find older code that has them.  Feel free to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

In **most** cases a D-spec prototype is not required.  However, a prototype *is* required if the subprocedure returns a value *and* you use "LIKE(subprocedure-name)" to declare variables like the return value.

```
d doStuff         pr            10a                               
d  input                              like(doStuff)               
d                                     const
```

In the above example, the parameter "input" is defined like the return value of the subprocedure "doStuff".  If you do not include the D-spec prototype, the program will not compile.